# Set bean priority in application.yml

Tags: java, spring

I've got 2 spring beans

```
@Bean
public CacheManager hazelcastCacheManger() {
    ...
}

@Bean
public CacheManager infinispanCacheManger() {
    ...
}
```

How can I set which bean of type CacheManager to use in my application in my application.yml property file? Maybe something like parametrized qualifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indicate `@Profile` on bean declaration:

```
@Bean
@Profile("profile1")
public CacheManager hazelcastCacheManger() {
    ...
}

@Bean
@Profile("profile2")
public CacheManager infinispanCacheManger() {
    ...
}
```

and in `application.yml` indicate which profile is active:

```
spring:
   profiles: 
      active:profile2
```

Here is more details [Profile based properties and yaml example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/).

If you need different profile for different launch you can specify the active profile at JVM launch properties.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=profile2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for spring profiles :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

You can tell for each bean on which profile it should be injected :

```
@Configuration
@Profile("hazelcast")
public class ConfHazelcast {
  @Bean
  public CacheManager hazelcastCacheManger() {
      ...
  }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("infinispan")
public class ConfInfinispan {
  @Bean
  public CacheManager infinispanCacheManger() {
      ...
  }
}
```

And then start your project with the right profile :

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=hazelcast -jar app.jar
```

Comment: As i know you can set profile in your yaml config too

 https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Answer (score 1):

> you can mark @Primary on one bean. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary